# How can I plot the following pandas data set with three columns using matplotlib?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, multiple-columns

I am able to plot the data set below when it only has the last two columns (the GDP per year and the population value) but I want to learn how to plot it to also include the year.

`suicides_gdp = suicides_russia.groupby(["year", " gdp_for_year ($) "])["suicides_no"].sum()`
`suicides_gdp`

`year   gdp_for_year ($)`
`1989  506,500,173,960       37921`
`1990  516,814,274,022       39028`
`1991  517,962,962,963       39281`
`1992  460,290,556,901       45923`
`1993  435,083,713,851       55846`
`1994  395,077,301,248       61420`
`1995  395,531,066,563       60548`
`1996  391,719,993,757       57511`
`1997  404,926,534,140       54746`
`1998  270,953,116,950       51518`
`1999  195,905,767,669       56974`
`2000  259,708,496,267       56619`
`2001  306,602,673,980       56958`
`2002  345,110,438,692       55024`
`2003  430,347,770,732       51445`
`2004  591,016,690,743       49096`
`2005  764,017,107,992       45802`
`2006  989,930,542,279       42614`
`2007  1,299,705,247,686     41149`
`2008  1,660,844,408,500     38211`
`2009  1,222,643,696,992     37408`
`2010  1,524,916,112,079     33356`
`2011  2,051,661,732,060     31038`
`2012  2,210,256,976,945     29643`
`2013  2,297,128,039,058     28690`
`2014  2,063,662,665,172     26541`
`2015  1,368,400,705,491     25432`

I tried `plt.plot(suicides_gdp.index, suicides_gdp.values)` and `plt.barh(x="suicides_no", y=["year", " gdp_for_year ($) "], width=5)` but I get the following errors respectively:

`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` for the line plot and `TypeError: bar() got multiple values for keyword argument 'x'` for the horizontal bar chart.

How can I plot the following data set using either a line plot or bar chart?

Answer (score 2):

I would plot `bar`, instead of `barh`. Also, since the two columns have different scales, it's best to plot them in twin axes:

```
suicides_gdp = suicides_gdp.reset_index()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,6))
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(suicides_gdp['year'], suicides_gdp['suicides_no'], 
        color='C1', alpha=0.5)
ax.plot(suicides_gdp['year'], suicides_gdp['gdp_for_year ($)'], zorder=100)
plt.show()
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you saw already, the function `barh` only two arguments which means two dimensions. That means it allows to represent only two columns. If you want to represent three columns, you have two options :

1. Make tree graphs, in which you represent your columns by two,
2. Use a 3D plot. I know such plots exist in Matlab. In matplotlib you have [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/index.html), for example, which allows to represent data in 3D.